# vue computed cannot get the the attributes in the object

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Account to the [defind of vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/zh-cn/forms.html)

```
// inside mutations
mutations: {
  updateMessage (state, message) {
    state.obj.message = message
  }
}
// html
<input v-model="message">
// ...
computed: {
  message: {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state.obj.message
    },
    set (value) {
      this.$store.commit('updateMessage', value)
    }
  }
}
```

and I code this

```
<input type="text" v-model="data.reference">
data () {
    return {
      data:{
          ...
          reference: '',
      }
    }
  },
computed: {
    'data.reference':{
        get () {
            return this.$store.state.currentKbdata.reference
        },
        set (value) {
            console.log(222)
            this.$store.commit('updateReference', value)
        }
    }
  }
```

And when i enter the input the 222 is not show up

.........................................................................

Comment: Sorry.  It is not clear what you are doing.  Why do you have single quotes around `'data.reference':` ?

Comment: Because when I init the data, it is a array for the form.And the input is one of the data

Comment: I am fairly certain that `'data.reference'` will just be recognized as a string.  Do you not have errors in the browser console?   Besides that you are defining a property twice.  That is, in both the data() object and as a computed property.

Comment: But ```data.reference``` work for watch.

Comment: Ok.  But I am betting you still have error messages in the console that you have not posted here.

Comment: no...no console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define computed getters with dot notation like you can watchers. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q0oahL3q/68/) of that not working, where you can see the error in the console reads:

> Cannot read property 'reference' of undefined.

Also, it appears that you are attempting to define a computed property that already exists as a property defined in the `data` method. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v3ohzsz/), you can see that that also won't work. The value defined in the `data` method takes precedence over the computed property definition.

---

Anyways, from your example, I don't see why you need to create a computed property on a nested object property at all.

Just use a normal definition for a computed property:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    reference: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    updateReference(state, reference) {
      state.reference = reference;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    reference: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.reference;
      },
      set(val) {
       this.$store.commit('updateReference', val);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="reference">
  {{ $store.state.reference }}
</div>
```

---

If you really need to set the value of `data.reference`, then there are many ways you could make that happen. One would be to turn it into a computed property as well:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    reference: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    updateReference(state, reference) {
      state.reference = reference;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    reference: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.reference;
      },
      set(val) {
       this.$store.commit('updateReference', val);
      }
    },
    data() {
      return { reference: this.reference };
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.15/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="reference">
  <div>data.reference: {{ data.reference }}</div>
  <div>$store.state.reference: {{ $store.state.reference }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/q0oahL3q/74/](https://jsfiddle.net/q0oahL3q/74/)
I add the data and the console is not exit...

Comment: You didn't follow any of my suggestions... You still have a `data` property in the `data` method so it takes precedence over the `data.reference` computed, which, as I explained, wouldn't work anyways. Remove the `data` property and you'll see the error.